# php - if dynamic variables are identical

Tags: php, sql, combinations, probability

I fetch a bunch of records from my database and loop through them:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM driving_list_shipments WHERE id IN($allIds)";
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($stmt as $row){ 

}
```

Now, my `$row[]` contains below:

```
$row["id"]; //Row id from database table
$row["temperature"]; //Values can be: 2-8, 15-25, No Temperature
$row["dgr"]; //Values can be: 0,1
$row["eq"]; //Values can be: 0,1
$row["ice"]; //Values can be: 0,1
$row["pil"]; //Values can be: 0,1
```

Obviously, above conditions can make a lot of different combinations. I am trying to figure out how to add the records that have the **exact** same conditions to their respective arrays.

**Example #1:** 
If row id 10, 20 and 30 have `$row["dgr"] = "1"` and `$row["temperature"] = "2-8"`, then I want these records to be added to an array (since they all have identical conditions).

I am not sure on how to do the check, since I cannot just `$condition1 = $condition2`, due to the fact that there are hundreds of different outcomes.

**Example #2:**

```
if($row["dgr"] == 0 && $row["eq"] == 1){ 
  echo $row["id"]; //Show the ids that matches above condition 
}
if($row["dgr"] == 1 && $row["eq"] == 0){ 
  echo $row["id"]; //Show the ids that matches above condition 
}    
if($row["dgr"] == 0 && $row["eq"] == 0){ 
  echo $row["id"]; //Show the ids that matches above condition 
}
```

As you can see above, these are just some of the possible combinations. If I have to "manually" check for all 5 conditions and the hundreds of different combinations, it will take me forever.

Comment: Can you show an example output of a couple variations of what you're expecting?

Comment: @RossWilson Added 2nd example

Comment: @James Would you mind showing an example of this? If I compare arrays with the next loop, how does that check the different combinations?

Comment: You might want to consider using a GROUP BY statement?

Comment: You have multiple fields of data per row, so which ones do you want to match? E.g. do you only want to match the ones which are 0 or 1? Or do you want to match temperatures? What if "dgr" is 0 in two of them but "eq" is 0 in one and 1 in the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be what you're after but you could use `GROUP BY and`group_concat` in your query to achieve this:

```
SELECT `temperature`,`dgr`,`eq`,`ice`,`pil`, GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) as `ids` FROM `driving_list_shipments` WHERE id IN($allIds) GROUP BY `temperature`,`dgr`,`eq`,`ice`,`pil`
```

Then you use `explode` to make the ids into an array e.g.

```
explode(',', $row['ids'])
```

Comment: nice, we posted nearly the same thing.

Comment: @Leroy Haha, yes we did ;)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could get them by writing a query instead of checking them in PHP loop.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM driving_list_shipments WHERE id IN($allIds) AND dgr='1' AND temperature='2-8'";
```

Or actually I mean Write a loop that grab for you the correct data instead of loop through all data:

```
$rules = array (
  array ('dgr' => '1', 'temperature'=> '2-8'),
  array ('dgr' => '0', 'temperature'=> '2-8')
);   
for ($rulse as $rule) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM driving_list_shipments WHERE id IN($allIds) AND dgr='".$rule['dgr']."' AND temperature='".$rule['temperature']."'";
  $stmt = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: I have hundreds of different combinations. As stated in my OP, I am not able to list all the hundreds kind of combinations into the script directly.

Comment: So I think u could write all different possible values for each property and then make $rules array from that by Math. Then use for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you a result of which id's are matched to a specific temperature and dgr. Maybe the result of this can be queried over. And be assigned to a specific variable.

```
SELECT temperature, dgr, GROUP_CONCAT(id) as ids FROM driving_list_shipments WHERE id IN($allIds) GROUP BY temperature, dgr
```